# How to increase stamina and how to cure injured players?

Tags: fifa-online-3

How do I increase the stamina level of a player and how do I cure a player who is injured? Normally an injury in Fifa Online 3 would last only for one match but now I played more than 6 games an the player is still injured.

Answer (score 1):

To increase stamina, you should just put them in your reserves/sub. Then play a LEAGUE or cup game using your own club. If you happen to use a different club (temp) for a cup etc, your injured won't heal nor the stamina increase.